# What’s the word for "ninja’d" in publishing things?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, formality

I am looking for the word for a situation like this:

Someone is planning to make a big instructional video on how to fold fitted
sheets, but just before finishing the big project, someone else uploads
their own video about the very same thing, which becomes popular.  Then 
that other popular video has **(*ninja’d*)** the other guy.

I’m sure there is a more established word for this than *ninja’d*, but I 
just can’t think of what it is. And I’ve been thinking about this in the
back of my head for quite a while now.

---

PS: For those who don’t know what *ninja’d* is, I apologise, it’s just the
best-fitting word for me; per [Urban
Dictionary](http://urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ninja%27d).

Comment: BTW Joey I really didn't know the "ninja'd" term!  Thanks!

Comment: Just BTW a similar term for what you describe is "beaten to the punch".

Comment: @JoeBlow No problem. And thanks for the additional suggestion.

Comment: As Richard says, if the material is "news", you can be ***scooped***. If it's "academic research", you're more likely to be [***preempted***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=publish+research+paper+preempt&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=publish+research+paper+preempt&aqs=chrome..69i57.4821406j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8). More generally, although I've been *beaten to the punch* by @Joe there, at least I haven't been ***pipped at the post*** with this one!

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's a really good summary. You should post it as an answer too

Comment: pipped at the post!  perfect

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In publishing, you'd almost certainly want to consider "***Scooped***"; Securing or creating important original content only to discover that another person has beaten you to the presses.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoop_(term)

--

Here's the actual definition from the OED

> "*A piece of news published by a newspaper or broadcast by a
>   television or radio station in advance of its rivals. Reporters at the
>   city's three tabloid papers usually compete for scoops.*"

Comment: Although this is probably the word I'm looking for, and I have seen this word being used this context, I can't seem to find any formal definitions of this usage for 'scoop' or 'to scoop'. Would you know any site that does have a formal definition? Or is this just informal language to begin with?

Comment: It's definitely a slang term but I think most people would understand it.

Comment: @Joeytje50 Various dictionary definitions here - http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scoop

Comment: @Frank not really 'various' definitions, just noun definition 10 and transitive verb definition 4 that basically says the same as def. 10. Also, if you read my comment carefully, I said 'formal definitions', and these 2 are both labeled *informal*.

Comment: Hi Joey - that's not how dictionaries work.  If a word happens to be marked "informal" that does not mean it is "less of a word". It's the **second** definition, so highly important and strongly-typed.

Comment: @Joeytje50 'Various' was for the various dictionaries. 'formal', I took to mean 'from a well respected dictionary'. I doubt you'll find it defined as anything other than 'informal' or 'slang'. OED has it as slang with the first mention from 1886 (US).

Comment: And indeed, it's completely incorrect that it is still marked "informal". It's no more "informal" than say "television" "ad" or "car".

Comment: It's certainly of longer standing, more widely understood, and has had a stronger impact upon literature and culture (e.g. Evelyn Waugh's novel *Scoop*) than *ninja'd*.

Answer (score 5):

If you'll take a phrase rather than a single word, you can also say the other person **stole your thunder**.  This has much wider application than publishing (two people making verbal presentations at the same meeting, for example), though.

@FumbleFingers, in a comment on the original post here, suggests being **beaten to the punch**, which also fits really well.  (I'll take this out of mine if FumbleFingers puts it in their own answer, I'm just trying to get it where people are more likely to see it).

Another term that is somewhat related would be to say **they ate my lunch**, which usually (as I have heard it) refers to someone capitalizing on a business opportunity that would likely have been yours had that other person not done so.  It doesn't necessarily carry the connotation of beating someone to market, though--mostly I've heard it when a new competitor comes in and gets the business that a larger or more established entity had been getting dependably for years.

Comment: Back when hunting with hounds was seen as sport in England, there was the phrase **they shot your fox**.

Answer (score 2):

In the world of chess problems, we say that the problem published earlier **anticipated** the one published later. We may also describe the later one as anticipated.